# Hurst exponent with R

Tags: r, time-series

I would like calculate the Hurst exponent with R. Is there a library or built in function that can do this? any suggestion will be appreciated (even weblinks to references).

update: thanks to the comment of Ben Bolker, I have found this script in the example of the function

```
hurst.est(wspec, range, nvoice, plot=TRUE)
```

at this page http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/Rwave/html/hurst.est.html

script:

```
wnoise <- rnorm(8192)
plot.ts(wnoise)
spwnoise <- fft(wnoise)
spwnoise <- Mod(spwnoise)
spwnoise <- spwnoise*spwnoise
plot(spwnoise[1:4096], log="xy", type="l")
lswnoise <- lsfit(log10(1:4096), log10(spwnoise[1:4096]))
abline(lswnoise$coef)
cwtwnoise <- DOG(wnoise, 10, 5, 1, plot=FALSE)
mcwtwnoise <- Mod(cwtwnoise)
mcwtwnoise <- mcwtwnoise*mcwtwnoise
wspwnoise <- tfmean(mcwtwnoise, plot=FALSE)
wspec.pl(wspwnoise, 5)
hurst.est(wspwnoise, 1:50, 5)
```

I guess that the first part generate a signal with memory effect, but I can't understand which part of the second part of code is strictly necessary to estimate the hurst exponent. Who can help me and would explain this? I am in doubt with

```
mcwtwnoise <- Mod(cwtwnoise)
mcwtwnoise <- mcwtwnoise*mcwtwnoise
```

Comment: `install.packages("sos"); library("sos"); findFn("hurst exponent")`

Comment: Ben I was just cominf back to reply with exactly thee same comment. +1 for teaching a man to fish.

Comment: @Tyler: you know the rule, "... teach a man to fish and you've lost a customer for life"  :-)

Comment: @Carl these customers don't pay :)

Comment: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/unmainmisc.html : "If you give someone a program, you will frustrate them for a day; if you teach them how to program, you will frustrate them for a lifetime."

Comment: see the following question on the fractal Hurst library
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867047/fractal-package-in-r-does-it-work/65927349#65927349)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Converted from a comment.)

This isn't exactly an answer, but

```
install.packages("sos")
library("sos")
findFn("hurst exponent")
```

should get you there pretty quickly.  *Notes*: (1) you only need to do `install.packages(...)` once per installation of R, but `library("sos")` in every session; (2) you still need to work out whether the packages that you find this way are doing what you need -- but at least you know where to start.

Comment: Agreed Dirk but I personally think that the results from sos are a little more easy to sift through and focused (I guess they're aesthetically pleasing).

Answer (score 5):

Hurst exponent, H,  can be calculated from fractal dimension, D, as D = 2 - H.

I use the fractaldim package, available CRAN, to calculate fractal dimension. There is a complete description of the methodologies in Estimators of Fractal Dimension: Assessing the Roughness of Time Series and Spatial Data. University of Washington, Department of Statistics, Technical Report no. 577, http://www.stat.washington.edu/research/reports/2010/tr577.pdf.

With this package you can apply wavelet transforms, boxcount, etc. or the recommended madogram algorithm to calculate fractal dimension.

Answer (score 2):

The Rwave package uses a wavelet transform to estimate the Hurst exponent so you might want to try the fArma package. It has a variety of other functions to estimate the Hurst exponent aside from wavelets. Isn't listed on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fArma/) other than an archive for now but it works for me.

Here's the relevant documentation section from the package. http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=fArma:LrdModelling

Answer (score 0):

The most full set of methods (nine) is given in package `fArma' '(LrdModelling)` function `hurstSlider`.

Answer (score 0):

There is number of built in hurst Libraries one in pracma library, one in portfolioAnalytics library, and another in the fractal library example below

`````
    HurstIndex(nvr)

    library(pracma)
    hurstexp(nvr)
    library(fractal)
    hurstSpec(nvr)````
#They are R scripts.
`````

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and closes to Mandelbrots implementation of Hurst's index is from the pracma library and the hurstexp(x) command.
The fractal library no longer runs and is removed from cran. And I flagged an error in the calculation of the portfolioAnalytics HurstIndex command, to which they never corrected or adjusted, the portfolioAnalytics Hurst command is best to be completely ignored , it gives completely wrong or at best misleading answers.