# Fractal Package in R - Does it work?

Tags: r

When I run the example code for a random walk using the fractal package:

```
library(fractal)
## create test series 
set.seed(100)
x <- rnorm(1024)
walk <- cumsum(x)

 ## calculate the Hurst coefficient of a random 
## walk series using various techniques 
methods <- c("aggabs","aggvar","diffvar","higuchi")
z <- lapply(methods, function(method, walk){
hurstBlock(ifelse1(method=="higuchi",diff(walk),walk), method=method)  
},walk=walk )
names(z) <- methods

## plot results 
old.plt <- splitplot(2,2,1)
for (i in 1:4){
    if (i > 1)
       splitplot(2,2,i)
    plot(z[[i]], key=FALSE)
    mtext(paste(attr(z[[i]],"stat.name"), round(as.numeric(z[[i]]),3), sep=", H="),
       line=0.5, adj=1)
}
 par(old.plt)
```

I do not get hurst exponent of .5? I understand the there are different method of calculations but I believe AggVar is most like the R/S rescale method and for a brownian motion this should return .5 not .94 like it does.

SHouldn't it be .5?

Also if you change

walk <- cumsum(x)  to

walk <- x    Then this is white noise and I should get a Hurst Exponent of 0. But I dont.

Can you help clarify?

Comment: A quick game of google suggests 0.5 corresponds to white noise, not normal (gaussian) distribution.  Do you have sources which quote Hurst values for specific distributions?

Comment: .5 = brownian motion i.e. a pure random walk  and 0 = white noise which is pure mean reversion with expectation = 0. This is on wikipedia or any other site.

Answer (score 0):

I have done extensive testing of the three most prominent Hurst exponent libraries since my answer above and posted a video on youtube, However, from fractal, the most common, Hurst estimator used is the hurstpec from fractal and the hurstexp from the pracma library. The other estimator from PerformanceAnalytics econometrics finance library does not seem to be right no matter what estimate you use. I left on the Authors Github maintenance site an error correction request or check, I have not checked back to see the response, I left the request 4 months ago.

```
iwm_rt <- dailyReturn(IWM, type ="log")
```

head(iwm_rt)

````
```{r}
library(pracma)
library(fractal)

x <- iwm_rt


hurstBlock(x, method="aggAbs", scale.min=8, scale.max=NULL,
           scale.ratio=9, weight=function(x) rep(1,length(x)), fit=lm)





fit_aggab <- hurstBlock(x, method="aggAbs", scale.min=8, scale.max=NULL,
           scale.ratio=9, weight=function(x) rep(1,length(x)), fit=lm)

plot(fit_aggab)

RoverS(x, n.block.min=22, scale.ratio=9, scale.min=8)
````

```
hurstSpec(x, method="standard", freq.max=0.25, dc=FALSE, n.block=NULL,
          weight=function(x) rep(1,length(x)), fit=lm, sdf.method="direct")


hurstexp(x)
```

*The aggabs method from hurstblock in fractal is an aggregate estimate from a large sample time series, the most crucial factor in fitting the aggabs estimator is the scale.ratio estimate I solve it by trial and error which is a bit tedious but I do not know of a more scientific method, the scale. ratio is the multiplier for each subsequent series of samples from the time series*

Comment: Yes I initialled used the similar graphing technique from the example which you have derived your question from also, it does not work, that easily you have to deeply understand each parameter involved the estimates are very sensitive to parameter estimates their is little tolerance for error or parameters even slightly outside of the exact domain of the estimate. I found for my purposes the aggabs estimate was all that i needed and included how I  plot the chart below.

Comment: You were not getting the wrong answers the way you were inputting your parameters was incorrect, try them individually and plot, before combining with a loop into a grid of charts.

Comment: The fractal() library has been deprecated and removed from cran repository it will not run on any r implementation above 4.